# full width jquery slide link not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, slider

I've customised the jQuery slideshow plugin Supersized (Google it as I can only post 2 links and those are needed below :-) )

I have no need for it to be fullscreen so I've set my height to be 475px and I also have no need for the slider controls either (although keyboard nav is enabled).

[I have the slider working to a degree](http://picsel.generichost.co.uk/slider/demo.html) - there's a link on the last slide and it can be clicked. The elements are of fixed position.

[I have the same slider here](http://picsel.com/) - the CSS is a bit different (not using fixed positioning) but the link just doesn't want to make itself known, even although Firebug is showing it's there.

This has had be stumped for the past day now and I'd be eternally grateful for any solutions.

I'm surprised that there are no other full width sliders out there that do what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance,
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error lies in those line :

```
#supersized a.activeslide {
    z-index: -10;
}

#supersized a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111;
    display: block;
    height: 475px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -30;
}

#supersized {
    height: 475px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
}

#supersized a.prevslide {
    z-index: -20;
}
```

The z-index are negative, putting your supersized stuff **under** other *content*. It's like putting a transparent div over a link : the link become unclickable.

Easy way to confirm : *right click -> inspect element* put you on #sliderContainer and not on the img.

Fix :

instead of -999, -30, -20 and -10 for z-index, use something like 10,20,30,40 (same order)

**Edit** :
The reason negative z-index are used is because this plugin is made to make page-wide background 
(ie, put your images under all your content).

Your slider is also rather frustrating : you have to wait till the right image load to click on the link (4 images sliding, 1 with a link). I suggest you to either put the link on all images or to add a way to navigate between the images.

Comment: another reason to use positive indexes: negative z-index can cause problems in certain browsers.

Comment: Thanks. Keyboard nav is enabled, should have added that. We haven't decided on the links yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility ​​to change the z-index values in the index.html.

```
<!--Thumbnail Navigation-->
        <div id="prevthumb" style="z-index: 20;"></div>
        <div id="nextthumb" style="z-index: 20;"></div>

        <!--Arrow Navigation-->
        <a id="prevslide" class="load-item" style="z-index: 20;"></a> <a id="nextslide"
            class="load-item" style="z-index: 20;"></a>


        <!--        <div id="thumb-tray" class="load-item"> -->
        <!--            <div id="thumb-back"></div> -->
        <!--            <div id="thumb-forward"></div> -->
        <!--        </div> -->

        <!--Time Bar-->
        <!--        <div id="progress-back" class="load-item"> -->
        <!--            <div id="progress-bar"></div> -->
        <!--        </div> -->

        <!--Control Bar-->
        <!--        <div id="controls-wrapper" class="load-item">  -->
        <!--            <div id="controls">  -->

        <!--                <a id="play-button"><img id="pauseplay" src="jquery/img/pause.png" /> </a>  -->

        <!--Slide counter-->
        <!--                <div id="slidecounter">  -->
        <!--                    <span class="slidenumber"></span> / <span class="totalslides"></span>  -->
        <!--                </div> -->

        <!--Slide captions displayed here-->
        <!--            <div id="slidecaption"></div> -->

                <div id="slidecaption" style="z-index: 20;"></div>


        <!--Thumb Tray button-->
        <!--                <a id="tray-button"><img id="tray-arrow" -->
        <!--                    src="jquery/img/button-tray-up.png" /> </a> -->

        <!--Navigation-->
        <!--                <ul id="slide-list"></ul> -->

        <!--            </div> -->
        <!--        </div> -->
```

When you edit it with this possibility, the link of the image is working!
So you don´t have to change things in the css file.